# Retrieve integer value of enum

Tags: c#-4.0

Given:

```
public enum myType
{
    Val1 = 1,
    Val2 = 2,
    Val3 = 3
}
```

and code elsewhere in the app where a value :
   ...
   row.myType // resolves to Val1
   ...

I need to translate row.myType to **1**

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Enums returning int value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943398/c-enums-returning-int-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply cast to an int:

```
int enumValue = (int)row.MyTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

cast it to int

> (int)row.myTime

Answer (score 0):

You can simply cast it to an integer:

```
(int)row.myType;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myType someEnumVal = myType.Val1;
int intValOfEnum = (int)someEnumVal;
```