# C#, cast variable to Enum.GetUnderlyingType

Tags: c#, .net, casting, enums

Suppose I have enum, which underlying type is byte:

```
enum EmpType : byte
{
    Manager = 1,
    Worker = 2,
}
```

Can I cast some int literal to underlying type of this enum(byte in this case) ?

Something like this doesn't work (Error: "; expected"):

```
byte x = (Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(EmpType)))15;
```

Can I cast to underlying type without explicitly writing (byte)15 ?

Thanks.

Comment: This question makes no sense to me;. What are you trying to achieve with this shenanigan?

Comment: Enum.GetUnderlyingType returns a Type.  So this is trying to cast 15 to class Type

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: He wants to do a cast to a type that is the underlying type of an enum, without having to specify again what that type is.

Comment: @Patashu: That's rather obvious. The question is why, because this is more a solution looking for a problem than a true problem. And what on earth id the point of attempting to cast 15 to an **enum** with values ranging from 1 to 2?

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens: This was just a theoretical question. I'm not going to implement it in real code. Just was wondering how to do that.
And by the way, I'm not casting 15 to enum values of 1 or 2, I'm trying to cast to byte value.

Comment: You should have stated that in your original post. Bad data will get you bad answers, and lose you friends.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the following will work.  But I'm not sure it will get you the desired behavior in all cases.

```
var x = Convert.ChangeType(15, Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(EmpType)))
```

Comment: Glad to help!  But be careful with it.  It's pretty odd.

Comment: Even now in the future I found this very useful in a generic helper method that enumerates all flags in an enum, optionally retrieving the value of the underlying type.

Comment: Here's another valid and reasonable application:  Treating enums as their underlying types in a switch statement that takes an `object` and has switch-on-type style cases.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do. Below is a related question about casting ints to enums and vice-versa, the same applies to byte in this case.

[Is it possible to cast integer to enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899498/is-it-possible-to-cast-enum-to-integer)

If you want to detect the underlying type at run-time... it seems awkward and a lot of work. You could just do a case statement based upon the name of the underlying type. I'm not sure what good it would do you due to type safety concerns.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but thank you for useful links.