# How do I convert a string to an enum value to an integer?

Tags: c#, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I Convert a string to an enum in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-c)
>   [Enums returning int value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943398/enums-returning-int-value)

I have declare an enumeration:-

```
public enum Car
        {
            SELECT = 0,
            AUDI = 1,
            NISSAN = 2,
            HONDA = 3,
            LINCOLN = 4
        }
```

Now I need the int value of enum where it matches:-

```
private int GetCarType(string CarName)
        {
            foreach(var item in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Car))
            {
                if (item.ToLower().Equals(CarName.ToLower()))
                    //return int value of Enum of matched item; ???????
            }
```

Result expected:-

```
int i = GetCarType(CarName); //suppose CarName is AUDI, it should return 1;
Console.write(i);

Result :- 1
```

How will I get value of enum? And better coding practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result = (int)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(Car), carName)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx

This replaces your `GetCarType` function.  You no longer have to iterate over the enum names.

Answer (score 6):

If you are converting a string to an enum, you should use [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse.aspx) rather than iterating over the names.

Then just cast to an integer:

```
var iAsInteger = (Int32)i;
```

Comment: You do mean `string to enum`?

Answer (score 3):

simply cast your enum to int like

```
int i=(int)Car.Audi;
```

this will give you 1

```
int i=(int)Car.Select;
```

this will give you 0

Comment: First you gotta match.. I don't know what is value of CarName..

Comment: @user1327064 you dont know? i am not getting you

Comment: @DevJob: Robert Harvey has answered my question. Your ones wont fit in..

Comment: @user1327064 i am glad mark's answer helped you mark it as answer it will help fellow peers

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = (int) Enum.Parse(typeof(Car), "AUDI");
```

Comment: Yep, 3 minutes. I'm a slow typer :-)