# Why are these enums bad

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, enums

In Visual Studio -- well, I am using Visual Studio 11 Beta, so that might be the issue -- I think I am coding enums ok.  But while this works:

[image]

This does not work:

[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: Do you have a C++ programming background?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what kind of triangle would (100, 1, 1) be?

Comment: @Greg:  oooo, you got a point.  It could not be a triangle at all !!

Comment: @ckUnderflow OK, obvious solution, I admit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nothing to do with the VS11 beta.  You just have to prefix with the enum name:

```
return TriangleType.error;
```

Answer (score 4):

C# is a strong typed language. You are missing the enum name before the enum value. This should work:

```
return TriangleType.error;
```

and so on...

Comment: Talking of strong typing regarding C# enums is a bit misleading, especially given that you could return values outside the enum, too ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to do as in your first example and return an int you could cast the value and still use the enum "names", as in:

```
return (int)TriangleType.scalene;
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943398/enums-returning-int-value) other SO question for more information.