# Enum type in constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, enums

So I have to initiate an object from a class into the main form, but the arguments I have to put in the constructor are from an enum type I made in that class.

```
    private List<Geluidsfragment> fragmenten;
    private enum ThemaSoorten 
    { 
        Muziek, 
        Luisterboeken, 
        Cabaretshows 
    }
```

^this part is now outside the class, as was advised.

```
// Constrcutors

    public BGExperience(ThemaSoorten thema)
    {
        fragmenten = new List<Geluidsfragment>();
        this.thema = thema;
    }
```

These are the fields and constructor for the field. Below is the initiation of the object of this class I need.

```
public GeluidsfragmentForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BGExperience bgExperience = new BGExperience("Muziek");
    }
```

So the overload has to be of the type ThemaSoorten and it has to be in the enum, but at this point it gets stuck.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: BGExperience bgExperience = new BGExperience(ThemaSoorten.thema1);

Comment: You need to declare the enum as `public`and probably outside of the class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the name of Enum value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16039037/get-the-name-of-enum-value)

Comment: You cannot specify a string value for an enum value like that, you can only specify numeric values. Why not use `public enum ThemaSoorten { Muziek, Luisterboeken, Cabaretshows };` ?

Comment: You cannot assign a string to the `enum` values (at least no in C# 4.0). [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/sbbt4032(v=vs.110).aspx) states "The approved types for an enum are byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, or ulong."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make first your `enum` to be public and then try this one:

```
BGExperience bgExperience = new BGExperience(BGExperience.ThemaSoorten.Muziek);
```

If you don't make your `enum` to be public, you will not be able to access it outside your class let alone to create an instance of your class.

**Update**

As correctly Sriram has already pointed out in his comments, it would be a better design approach to not make this `enum` to be a nested type. You could declare it outside of your class, like:

```
public enum ThemaSoorten 
{ 
    Muziek, 
    Luisterboeken, 
    Cabaretshows 
}
```

and then create a new `BGExperience` object as below:

```
var bgExperience = new BGExperience(ThemaSoorten.Muziek);
```

**Important Note** (thanks Selman22)

You can't declare an `enum` with the way you have already done it. This couldn't even compile. Furthermore, you should take an error message while you were typing this. Anyway, the correct way of defininit an `enum` is the following:

```
public enum EnumName
{
    Member1,
    Member2,
    Member3
}
```

In place of `EnumName` you should put the name of your `enum` and in place of `Member1`, `Member2` and `Member3` the names of the items in your enum. If you want this items have specific values, you should do it like:

```
public enum EnumName
{
    Member1 = 1,
    Member2 = 2,
    Member3 = 3
}
```

Comment: That still wont compile ;)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel yeah the enumeration is private and out of scope

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I suppose you were saying so, because the enum access modifier wasn't public. Correct?

Comment: @Christos Yes, my comment was made before you edited the answer. I still recommend to make the enum non nested type.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Thanks. I agree with you 100%. However I tried to give a solution in the context of OP.

Comment: how does this compile ? `thema1 = "Muziek",`

Comment: It doesn't, it's invalid syntax. You cannot specify a *string* value for an enum in C# or .NET, only a numeric value.

Comment: @Selman22 you are completely correct. My mistake...that I didn't pointed out and I replicated the erorr. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @Christos I now have defined it the way you said it but I still get the error "cannot implicitely convert type 'string' to 'int'"

Comment: @Lukas have you defined the `Enum` like in my answer, outside your class and pass the argument `ThemaSoorten.Muziek` to the constructor and still you get an error? The underlying type of an enum is an integral type. When we don't define explicitly the underlying type, then by default the underlying type of the enum is the int. When you set the first item of the enum to be `Member1` it's value is 0, the next member's value is 1 and so on. On the other hand, if you pass a string it's reasonable that you will get this error.

Comment: @Christos yes, I have done everything exactly like in your answer

Comment: @Lukas please check this https://dotnetfiddle.net/92opwE. There I don't get any error. So the problem should be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Or perhaps you want to provide string value of the enum to the constructor, then here is how it will work:

```
BGExperience bgExperience = new BGExperience((BGExperience.ThemaSoorten)Enum.Parse(typeof(BGExperience.ThemaSoorten), "Muziek"));
```

Make sure to make the enum public for that. Otherwise you have to provide string in the constructor and parsing it to the enum value within the constructor.

Answer (score -1):

```
BGExperience bgExperience = new BGExperience(ThemaSoorten.thema1);
```