# Is There A Simple Way to Convert These String Values To Enum?

Tags: c#

I'm working on a stock trading app that utilizes the broker's dll file and commands to makes requests through the API. The biggest challenge (to me at least) has been figuring out how to give the API the various data types it requires for input. Right now I'm working on some test code that will buy 1 share of a stock. Many of the necessary conversions I've been able to figure out but enum continues to elude me.

```
        InsertOrderRequest insertOrderRequest = new InsertOrderRequest();
        insertOrderRequest.m_accountNumber = "00000001";
        insertOrderRequest.m_symbolId = Convert.ToUInt64(1900028);
        insertOrderRequest.m_quantity = Convert.ToDouble(1);
        insertOrderRequest.m_orderType = "Market"; //Needs to be enum
        insertOrderRequest.m_timeInForce = "Day"; //Needs to be enum
        insertOrderRequest.m_action = "Buy"; //Needs to be enum
        insertOrderRequest.m_primaryRoute = "AUTO";
```

You can see the 3 lines that I've marked "Needs to be enum". Now I've gone into the object browser and determined that "Market", "Day", and "Buy" are the appropriate responses but they aren't the right data type. Is there a line of code similar to "Convert.ToDouble()" that will convert these from string to enum? Thanks.

Comment: Have you define the `Enum` for `OrderType, TimeInForce, and Action`? can you show it too?

Comment: The `API` requires a `string` or an `int` value? Your program can use enums for either one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the name of Enum value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16039037/get-the-name-of-enum-value)

Comment: See my answer in the possible duplicate for all things you can do with an enum converting to and fro.

Answer (score 2):

If the strings match the name from an enum, you can parse them like this:

```
(OrderType) Enum.Parse(typeof(OrderType), "Market");
```

Alternatively, there is also a [`TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499(v=vs.110).aspx) version you can use. Both versions have overloads to ignore the case when matching the name.

If the strings do not match the name from an enum, you will have to create your own mapper. Can be done using a simple switch case.

Comment: VS seems to like it. Let me finish setting up the test order and I'll see if it executes. Thanks a lot!