# Get int values of Enum[]

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I have a method such as:

```
public void DoIt(params MyEnum[] channels)
{

}
```

Is there a way to get the int values of the enums in the params?

I tried `var myInts = channels.Select(x => x.Value)` but no luck

Comment: What is the idea behind taking an array of enums?

Comment: @shahkalpesh I'm guessing "to express zero, one, or many values, expressed in terms of the enum, but using their underlying integer values internally"

Comment: @MarcGravell: Thanks. I guessed OP is looking for combining enum values using `FlagsAttribute`. Also, if an array is passed, enum values can be passed more than once.

Comment: In that case surely you would use a BitWise enum? Edit - what  shahkalpesh said

Comment: @Rebel that doesn't necessarily mean it is suitable for [Flags] usage

Comment: possible duplicate of [get-int-value-from-enum?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943398/get-int-value-from-enum?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var myInts = channels.Cast<int>();
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var ints = (int[]) (object) channels;
```

Comment: Nice, although undocumented.

Answer (score 5):

You can do a cast in the select clause:

```
var myInts = channels.Select(x => (int)x);
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way to do the same, without LINQ:

```
var vals = Array.ConvertAll(channels, c =>(int)c);
```

Answer (score 2):

`var myInts = channels.Select(x=x.Value)` this doesn't work because `=` needs to be `=> (int)x`

I think `var myInts = channels.Select(x => (int)x).ToArray();` will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
public void DoIt(params MyEnum[] channels)
{
   int[] ret = channels.Select(x => ((int)x)).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
var myInts = channels.Select(e => (int)e);
```

Or as a LINQ query:

```
var myInts = from e in channels select (int)e;
```

You could then call `ToArray()` or `ToList()` on `myInts` to get a `MyEnum[]` or a `List<MyEnum>`