# How do I get an enum value from my ASP.NET MVC property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums

In my ViewModel, I have a property that creates an enumeration for my form's drop down menu.

```
public enum Colors
    {
    [Description("Dark Red")]
    DarkRed = 0,
    [Description("Orange")]
    Orange = 1,
    [Description("Blue")]
    Blue = 2
    }
```

My Helper returns:

```
<select id="ddlColor">
    <option value="DarkRed">Dark Red</option>
    <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
</select>
```

However, when I call the property in my model, I only get the name and not the value, e.g. **DarkRed** and not **0**.

```
model.Selections = InsertForm(model.Color);
```

How can I cast this in my model reference so I get the *value* from the enum?

Comment: I would look at this one looks like they had similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943398/get-int-value-from-enum

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may have to cast the value like this:-

```
var value = (int)model.Color;
```

**NOTE:-**

All enumeration type have an underlying type, which can be any integral type except char.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily cast it to an `int`.

By default enums are `Int32`.

so you could say

```
var value = (int)model.Color;
```

Since you are using asp.net mvc, i'm going to assume that model.Selections is a `List<SelectListItem>`.

See below.

```
  public List<SelectListItem> GetList<TEnum>() where TEnum : struct
        {
            var items = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach (int value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)))
            {
                items.Add(new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = Enum.GetName(typeof(TEnum), value),
                    Value = value
                });
            } 
            return items;


        }
```

You can now say `model.Selections = GetList<Color>();`