# Specifying type of an enum in C# fails

Tags: c#, enums

I have an enum of type `uint` in my class and a function with a uint argument. But when I call that function (`setColor`) with an enum as argument, I get the error:

```
Error   3   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Test.Form1.colors' to 'uint'
```

This is my class:

```
namespace Test{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        enum color : uint {off, red, yellow};


        setColor(uint color){
         ...
        }

        MyFunction()
        {
         setColor(color.red);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is "colors" defined?

Comment: Sorry, miscopypasted my code. It was actually defined with `{}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get int value from enum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943398/get-int-value-from-enum)

Comment: Is there any reason why your method can't take a `color` type parameter instead of `uint`?

Answer (score 2):

You should read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx)

> The underlying type specifies how much storage is allocated for each enumerator. However, an **explicit cast is necessary to convert from enum type to an integral type.** For example, the following statement assigns the enumerator Sun to a variable of the type int by using a cast to convert from enum to int.
>
> `int x = (int)Days.Sun;`

Answer (score 1):

Cast to uint and define the enum with {}.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    enum color : uint {off, red, yellow};

    void setColor(uint color){

    }

    void MyFunction()
    {
        setColor((uint)color.red);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did define it with {}. Copy paste error. Why do i have to cast it to `uint` when I explicitly defined it as `uint`?

Comment: From MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/sbbt4032.aspx: 
"The underlying type specifies how much storage is allocated for each enumerator. However, an explicit cast is necessary to convert from enum type to an integral type."

Answer (score 1):

```
enum mycolor : uint
{
    off, 
    red, 
    yellow
}

void setColor(mycolor color ){ }

void MyFunction()
{
    setColor(mycolor.red);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
public partial class Form1: Form
{
    enum color : uint {off, red, yellow};


    void setColor(uint color){

    }

    void MyFunction()
    {
        setColor((uint)(color.red));
    }
}
```