# Get enum char value

Tags: c#, enums

I have an Enum:

```
 public enum SensorType
    {

        Normal ='N',

        Lunch ='C',

        ALL
    }
```

In my function:

```
private void GetData(SensorType type){

    var charValue = type.ToString(); // here I want to get the char value, not the string.
}
```

I want to get "N", or "C" etc. any clue?

Thanks

Comment: Already answered here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943398/get-int-value-from-enum

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just cast the value:

`char charValue = (char)type;`