# Switch case from enum index

Tags: c#

```
namespace TaskBarPlus {
public partial class Form2 : Form {
    public Form2() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public class General {
        public enum ProcessPriority { Low = 0, Normal = 1, High = 2 }; ProcessPriority _Priority;

        [Category("Settings"), DisplayName("Application Priority")] public ProcessPriority Priority {
            get { return _Priority; }
            set {
                _Priority = value;
                switch (value) {
                    case 0: Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.Idle;
                    case 1: Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.Normal;
                    case 2: Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.High;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        General general = new General();
        propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = general;
    }
}
```

}

> Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to
>   'Form2.General.ProcessPriority'. An explicit conversion exists (are
>   you missing a cast?)

Comment: Duplicate of [Get int value from enum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943398/get-int-value-from-enum)

Comment: Property `Priority` is `ProcessPriority` type, so `value` is too.

Comment: what's your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use the actual enumeration values in the switch statement

```
public class General {
    public enum ProcessPriority { Low = 0, Normal = 1, High = 2 }; 

    ProcessPriority _Priority;

    [Category("Settings"), DisplayName("Application Priority")] 
    public ProcessPriority Priority {
        get { return _Priority; }
        set {
            _Priority = value;
            switch (value) {
                case ProcessPriority.Low: 
                    Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.Idle;
                    break;
                case ProcessPriority.Normal: 
                    Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.Normal;
                    break;
                case ProcessPriority.High: 
                    Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.High;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The exception message states that it is not valid to implicitly cast an integer to ProcessPriority. It kind of makes sense, since `ProcessPriority priority = -423` wouldn't make much sense in the context of ProcessPriority. Since you explicitly knew the values, you could have alternatively cast the integer like so

```
case (PriorityClass) 1:
```

or alternatively

```
int priorityVal = (int) value;
switch (priorityVal) {
    case 0:
        ....
}
```

Comment: Error: Control cannot fall through from one case label ('case 0:') to another

Comment: great its work but how to use index with enum and call it in switch as case 0, case 1, ... ?

Comment: this work: public enum ProcessPriority:int { Low = 0, Normal = 1, High = 2 }; ProcessPriority _Priority; now I can switch with index

Answer (score 0):

That's because your property `Priority` is of type `ProcessPriority` as can be seen below

```
public ProcessPriority Priority {
```

So the `value is ProcessPriority` and in your `Switch` you are saying `case 0` where `0` is of `Int32` type.

You should rather say like

```
switch(value)
{
  case ProcessPriority.Idle:
  ....
}
```