# MVC Printing out each Enum value through @foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums

### Enum:

```
    public enum Enumenter
    {
        Products = 10,
        Users = 20,
        Actions = 30
    }
```

### my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<ServerDB.Tables.EntityType>

@{

    ViewBag.Title = "Infrastruktur";
}


<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>

        <h2>Infrastruktur</h2>
    </th>

    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var val in Enum.GetNames(typeof(ServerDB.Tables.Enum)))
{


    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayName((String.Format("{0}{1}", val, "2")))

        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <p>
            </p>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
}
@foreach (var Ost in Enum.(typeof(ServerDB.Tables.Enum)))
{
    @Html.DisplayName((String.Format("{0}", Ost)))
}

</table>
```

How do i Print out The values next to the products?
im going to use the numbers from the enum to make a query search, so i can search for any product, any users or actions for that matter.
im no expert in this, so please be gentle.

Comment: you have to cast it to ``int`` like : ``Convert.ToInt32(val)``

Comment: Can you explain or link me to what "casting" is? And many thanks for the help.

Comment: you need value againt enum text so you have to cast it to `int` as the values are ``int``

Comment: see :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943398/get-int-value-from-enum

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.parse?view=net-7.0#system-enum-parse(system-type-system-string) has the example showing how to use Enum.GetNames() in tandem with Enum.Parse() (similar example in Enum.GetValues() section)

Answer (score 3):

`Enum.GetValues` returns values for the enum as objects, so you need to cast them to `int` value (using `int` instead of `var` will do that for you). After that you can use `Enum.GetName` to get the name for specific value:

```
@foreach (int val in Enum.Values(typeof(ServerDB.Tables.Enum)))
{
   var name = Enum.GetName(typeof(ServerDB.Tables.Enum), val);

    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayName((String.Format("{0}{1}", name, "2")))

        </td>
        <td>
            @val
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>

            </p>
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

There is another approach which doesn't use the `Enum.GetName` method. You simply cast the value you get from `Enum.Values` to `string` to get the name and to `int` to get the value

```
@foreach (var name in Enum.Values(typeof(ServerDB.Tables.Enum)))
{
    var val = (int)name;
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayName((String.Format("{0}{1}", name, "2")))

        </td>
        <td>
            @val
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>

            </p>
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Now i end up with 2 names if i switch the "2" out.
https://gyazo.com/cf056f5bdff9d8812cbb48fd2f94d144

Comment: @user3439890 I've updated the answer, you should change the `var` to `int` keyword so that it gets the real value

Comment: @user3439890 Awesome, you can mark this as an answer :)

Comment: I think that you can do `val.ToString()`  instead of `Enum.GetName(typeof(ServerDB.Tables.Enum), val);`