# Do I need to cast and Enum and how do I do that?

Tags: c#

In my code I have this:

```
        var wordForm = new WordForm()
        {
            WordId = word.WordId,
            Definition = webWordForm.definition,
            SourceId = webWordForm.sourceId,
            StatusId = EStatus.Download,
            PosId = WordToPosId(webWordForm.partOfSpeech)
        };
```

I declared the Enum:

```
public enum EStatus {
    NotSet   = 0,
    New      = 1,
    Download = 2,
    Edited = 3
}
```

and the statusID:

```
public int StatusId { get; set; } // StatusId
```

Do I need to cast this to an int and if so how do I do that?

Comment: (int)EStatus.Download or Convert.ToInt32(EStatus.Download)

Comment: What is the type of WordForm.StatusId?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get int value from enum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943398/get-int-value-from-enum)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast the `Enum` as

```
StatusId = (int)EStatus.Download
```

Comment: Instead of spoonfeeding, give her something more like how Enum to int casting works. How enum is basically int values under the fabric. etc

Answer (score 1):

An explicit cast is needed if type of enum is declared. But the default value for enum is `int`

> Every enumeration type has an underlying type, which can be any
>   integral type except char.

So an example for this is:

```
enum Days : byte {Sat=1, Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri};
```

`Days` is declared as `byte` so an explicit cast is needed when assigning it to an `int` variable since the enum is declared as `byte`

```
int x = (int)Days.Sun;
```

> However, an explicit cast is necessary to convert from enum type to an
>   integral type.

So for your example there is no need to cast it since the underlying type of your enumeration is an `int`

This is from the documentation [enum c#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx).
Please take time to read API's.