# How to convert an enum to int automatically via FastMember?

Tags: c#, dapper, fastmember

I'm using `FastMember` to convert a `List<T>` to a `Datatable`. Some classes contain enums and this is causing problems when passing the datatables as a TVP to a stored procedure.

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public SomeEnum EnumHere {get; set;}
}

var dt = new DataTable();
using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(myObjectsList))
{
    dt.Load(reader);
}

db.Execute<ResultObject>("insert_objects", new { dt }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

`FastMember` converts the list, however the column for the enum has a `DataType` of `SomeEnum`. When passing the datatable as a TVP, the following exception is thrown:

> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in Dapper.dll
>
> Additional information: The type of column 'SomeEnum' is not supported.  The type is 'SomeEnum'

Is there a way to force `FastMember` to convert enums to int?

Comment: I proposed a title edit, because the question seems trivial and like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/943398/3950370

Comment: Could look like something that is not supported in FastMember: https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member/issues/10

Comment: Can you specify what kind of problems using enums causes?

Comment: Well, it seems like @Michael is right. Maybe you could change the enums to ints in your data model and provide extension methods to access them as enums?

Answer (score 3):

You can create an anonymous type to with the right properties:

```
var newObjects = from m in myObjectList
                 select new { m.Id, EnumHere = (int)m.EnumHere };

var dt = new DataTable();
using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(newObjects))
{
    dt.Load(reader);
}
```