# How to grab Enum Identifers value C#

Tags: c#, enums

Suppose you have a Enum like this:

```
public enum CardNumber
{
    Two = 2,
    Three = 3,
    Four = 4,
    Five = 5,
    Six = 6,
    Seven = 7,
    Eight = 8,
    Nine = 9,
    Ten = 10,
    Jack = 'J',
    Queen = 'Q',
    King = 'K',
    Ace = 'A',
}
```

And a loop like:

```
foreach (Suits suit in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Suits)))
{
    deck.Add(new Card()
    {
        Suits = suit,
        CardNumber = num,
        image = "~/img/" + suit  + num + Enum.GetValues(suit).ToString(),
    });
}
```

How can I get the identifers value? I tried doing the .GetValues() but I get I cannot conver suits to System.Type.

Thanks in advance.

Example I want the values 2, 3,4, 5, etc.

Comment: try cast it as its underlying enum type - except yours seems to be a mix

Comment: Casting it actually worked but it still returns "Two" not 2

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate question. The cards game are one of the most popular school assignements and solutions can be found everywhere on the web, not just SO.

Comment: Try this (int)Enum.GetValues(suit)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get int value from enum in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943398/get-int-value-from-enum-in-c-sharp)

Comment: What values do you expect to see for `Jack`, `Queen`, etc?

Comment: You are perhaps better of making a mapper to convert your enum to the desired string explicitly.

Comment: @Herohtar "J" "Q"

Comment: It's not a duplicate because the enum is not just ints.

Answer (score 1):

Your enum when a char is the numeric representation of the character. This can be converted back to the string.

```
public static string ToCardNumberText(CardNumber cardNumber)
{
    var cardNumberByte = (byte)cardNumber;
    return cardNumberByte > 10
        ? ((char)cardNumberByte).ToString()
        : cardNumberByte.ToString();
}
```