# Another enum vs. int

Tags: c#, enums

I need namespace-wide contants.
So I have the option to use enums, like:

```
public enum Token
{
    INFORMATIONAL,
    WARNING,
    ABORT,
    FATAL
};
```

But the disadvantage is, in WPF for example, that I need to convert them to int, now and then.

So I thought, why not

```
public static class Token 
{
    public const int
    INFORMATIONAL = 0,
    WARNING =1,
    ABORT = 2,
    FATAL = 3;
};
```

in the source, they look the same AND I have no conversion issues.
So what would be the reason for enums at all?
I'm clearly missing something.
What is the reason for enums?

Comment: _in WPF for example, that I need to convert them to int, now and then_ out of interest, can you provide an example?

Comment: So if you want to convert them to int then just do it? You can cast the enum. Or is this more of a philosophy question? Because then the reason is that an enum variable can only be one of those enums, and not set to something out of range.

Comment: Are you sure about that @JG3? Try it, you may be surprised.

Comment: @iakobski i've done it in the past but it has been a while, anyway this thread seems to agree with me, just cast the enum to an int: https://stackoverflow.com/a/943407/8306962

Comment: Yes, but it's been said several times, but it's not true. An enum variable can be a value that's not defined in the enum definition. Using the OP's definition a `Token` can only be 0-3. But this is not a compiler or run-time failure: `Token token = (Token)99;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Consideration**

With enum you define a type having some constants themselves "typed" (not the good word by I don't know how to say that).

The advantage between using enum values and constants is to be able to parse the values and to use the enum scope as a type.

So it is a better abstraction.

Also you don't need to care to define the values even if you can.

For example:

**Parsing enum values**

```
foreach ( var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Token) ) ...
```

**Passing enum parameter**

```
void Method(Token token) ...
```

**Declare a collection keyed by an enum**

```
var map = new Dictionary<Token, string>();
```

**Condition test**

```
if ( value == Token.INFORMATIONAL ) ...
```

**Easy of bit flags usage**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute

**Default item name ToString result**

```
Console.WriteLine(Token.INFORMATIONAL)
```

Will display the name of the value, not its value as for a constant.

So to display the value:

```
Console.WriteLine((int)Token.INFORMATIONAL)
```

**Conclusion**

With constants, you need to use reflexion to parse a list but it is ugly and not usefull at all and you can't pass them as a typed parameter.

Usage possibilities of constants is limited.

So enums and constants are not the same thing at all even the basic as int usage.

Thus using enum or constants depends on the usage you will do.

If you only need int values and don't care about segregation, choose constants.

If you care about type safety and need to do advanced things, choose enum.

One last word to say is that enum is to not care about the underlying value, so if you need to work with values, use constants, else enum.

Use what is the most natural thing.

Comment: As for the term "typed", the only terms I can think off are "strong typisation", "type checks". The closest Adjective I can think of is "strongly typed".

Answer (score 5):

Enums to my knowledge have only one advantage: Type Safety.

Edit: They also have that [Flag] option, wich helps with encoding a lot of settings in one variable. Thanks to John for reminding me.

There is this interesting article about [Primitive Obession](https://andrewlock.net/using-strongly-typed-entity-ids-to-avoid-primitive-obsession-part-1/) (and I am really surprised how often I got to link this since learned about it yesterday).

It applies to your case like this: If you just use Primtives everywhere, the compiler can not warn you as much. You might try to assign 42 to a variable that was only *supposed* to one of those constant values.

But trying to assign anything but valid values to a Enum? Pretty hard/impossible to do by accident.

Comment: Don't forget `[Flags]`. Enums make working with flags much easier than doing the equivalent task in say an `int`, especially the `HasFlag` method.

Comment: @John Added. Thanks, I forgot those.

Comment: It's also handy that you can display the string name for the enum, like `Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek);` will output `"Friday"`, not `"5"`

Comment: @RufusL: It is definitely a usefull fallback/debug string. I try avoiding using it for actuall User output of course (a `Dictionary<DayOfWeek, String>` can deal with those better and also Localisation). But I do like simple debug options.