# Why does is operator behave like == operator?

Tags: c#

Assume we have statement like this:

```
enum EngineType
{
   Gasoline,
   Diesel,
   Electric
}

var engine = EngineType.Electric;

if (engine is EngineType.Electric)
{
    // do something
}
```

Why does if statement is true. From microsoft documentation: 
**The is operator checks if the result of an expression is compatible with a given type**.

Isn't the left value type of EngineType (enum) and right value type of integer? 
Am I missing something?

Comment: Which version are you using? Attempting to compile your example results in a "The type name 'Electric' does not exist in the type 'EngineType'" compilation error, which I would expect since `EngineType.Electric` is not a type.

Comment: @Lee  I'm working with VS2019 C#7.0 so that must be it.

Comment: C# pattern matching in action?

Comment: @TanveerBadar: Precisely. This is a constant pattern.

Comment: [I can't get this to compile](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Qlovb9), it is explicitly breaking on the `is MyEnum.MyValue` syntax. Am I missing something or is this not valid syntax?

Comment: @Flater That is not true. The only requirement is a compiler that supports C# 7.0. You can even use this syntax in a .NET Framework 2.0 project as long as you're using a recent compiler. (Try it out yourself with VS2019)

Answer (score 2):

Because when you use the [is keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is) this way, you are actually doing Pattern Matching (starting with C# 7.0) :

> [Constant pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#constant-pattern), which tests whether an expression evaluates to a specified constant value.

Comment: @Flater False. You can use this in a .NET Framework that targets even as far back as .NET 2.0 if you wanted. You just have to be using a compiler that supports C# 7.0.

Comment: @Herohtar: Dotnetfiddle runs .Net 4.7.3 though so I'm expecting it to be C#7.3 (same release). But Dotnetfiddle doesn't explicitly mention the C# version, granted.

Comment: @Flater There's no telling what Dotnetfiddle is running behind the scenes, so you can't base anything on what does or doesn't work there. I can confirm that the syntax works when I create a .NET Framework 2.0 project using Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 1):

Because `is` in C# 7.0 supports **pattern matching**. In particular, it allows matching against a "constant pattern". To quote [from the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is) (emphasis mine):

> When performing pattern matching with the constant pattern, `is` tests whether an expression equals a specified constant. In C# 6 and earlier versions, the constant pattern is supported by the switch statement. Starting with C# 7.0, it's supported by the `is` statement as well. Its syntax is:
>
> ```
> expr is constant
> ```
>
> where *expr* is the expression to evaluate, and *constant* is the value to test for. *constant* can be any of the following constant expressions:
>
> - A literal value.
> - The name of a declared const variable.
> - **An enumeration constant.**

Answer (score 0):

Enums are full types. While internally they are represented and can be (implicitly?) cast into integers (the number type they use/equate to can be changed), they are each a distinct type.

This actually enables all those Additional typecheks that make them useful. We recently had a Question about why we do not just use int constants over Enums:

[Another enum vs. int](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58762796/3346583)

`is` compares types and **only** types. If you do not give it a type, it will just go and find the type of what you did give it. With the values primitive types it can be ambigious. It is a compiler/runtime detail if `1` is a Int16, Int32 or Int64 today. Indeed it will likely varry on the digit lenght of the constant I give it. Not something I can rely on.

It could propably tell you that `1.2` is not the same as type `1` (unless some braindead designer decided to use decimal or float values in both cases for once).

But all possible **values** of the type `EngineType` are of the type `EngineType`. That is a big reasons Enums are a *thing* in the first place. Exactly to allow such type checks.

Comment: Enums are types but `EngineType.Electric` is not a type so this doesn't fully answer the question.