# Why would you declare a variable as a type named after a class

Tags: c#, class, declaration

Using C# as an example. Say there is a class named ExampleClass and the variable is just value. Why would one declare a variable like this

```
private ExampleClass value;
```

Comment: What is the question? You can declare inside the class space private fields or properties or events. In this case you're declaring a "ExampleClass type" variable with name "value" in "only this class scope"

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't declare a variable named `value` unless there was some **unavoidable** **requirement** to do so.

The reason why is because it is not **meaningfully named**.

When we name variables meaningfully, our code becomes **self-documenting**. Well documented code is always worthy goal.

Answer (score 0):

This is a field and can be declared inside a class. Example:

```cs
private class Test
{
    private int _customField;
}
```

`_customField` is my field with type `int` (instead of `ExampleClass`). People use it to make something more accessible since C# isn't just functions, it's OOP.

Answer (score 0):

There is a thing called [Primitive Obsession](https://andrewlock.net/using-strongly-typed-entity-ids-to-avoid-primitive-obsession-part-1/). Using a class/specific type here is the solution to it.

If you use a class, you got all the Compiler Type checking to help you avoid invalid values.

Take [this Enum vs Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58762796/another-enum-vs-int/58762819) question for examples.