# c# Enum. Get number value like string

Tags: c#, enums

I have enum:

```
public enum AlertSubject
    {
        TouristVisa = 1,
        CarDamagene = 2,
        RentalForceClose = 3,
        CarAccident = 4
    }
```

how to get key like a string? I mean `"1"` for `AlertSubject.TouristVisa`

Comment: `((int)AlertSubject.TouristVisa).ToString();`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get int value from enum in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943398/get-int-value-from-enum-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Enums in C# are essentially aliases for numbers, which means you can pass them anywhere an `int` is expected or cast them to an `int`

Answer (score 2):

You can use corresponding string format:

```
var s = AlertSubject.TouristVisa.ToString("d");
```

[Enumeration format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/enumeration-format-strings):

> **D or d**. Displays the enumeration entry as an integer value in the shortest representation possible.