# CS0426 The type name ' ' does not exist in the type ' '

Tags: c#, asp.net, namespaces

I have a file with this code:

```
namespace A
{
    public enum DT
    {
        Byte = 0,
        SByte = 1,
        BCD8 = 2,
        Int16 = 3,
        UInt16 = 4,
        BCD16 = 5,
        Int32 = 6,
        UInt32 = 7,
        BCD32 = 8,
        Single = 9,
        String = 10,
        Structure = 11,
        WString = 12
    }
}
```

In my WebForm1.aspx.cs file, I want to use an element from code above. My WebForm1.aspx.cs looks like:

```
using A;
namespace SComm
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           A.DT tData = new A.DT.Int16;
           //some other code
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error CS0426:

> "The type Int16 does not exist in the type DT"

I suppose is because of the different namespaces. What should I do solve this error?

Comment: Should be `DT tData = DT.Int16;` methinks.

Comment: The 2 parts of code are in two different files, with different namespaces. DT is not recognized when I type DT tData...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# explicit initialization for Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410979/c-sharp-explicit-initialization-for-enum)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/enumeration-types and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum

Comment: The first example from the first microsoft link looks alike to what I want. `Day today = Day.Monday; int dayNumber =(int)today;`
But I get the above error when I try to use `Monday`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original post you were declaring a variable of type A but A is a namespace and also using new to create an enum which is not correct.  With the new it is looking for a type "Int16" in the type A.DT which obviously does not exist.  Its like this

```
A.DT tData = A.DT.Int16;
```

Comment: so if the above does not answer your question, what is the question?

Comment: I got what you said. Then how could I get `Int16` from enum?

Comment: as i have written it above.  note that it does not have "new" before A.DT.Int16

Comment: So, my code is:
`A.DT tData=A.DT.Int16`, but I get the error `CS0426 The type name ' ' does not exist in the type ' '`.

Comment: it isn't in your question, you have a new before A.DT.Int16.  Are you saying you get literally the error above with the type name ' ' etc  i.e. an empty set of ''