# Enum to int, why use type cast to int rather than Convert.ToInt32(Enum)?

Tags: c#, enums

Been looking at the `Enum` to `int` qa's, There are plenty of type casting of `(int)Enum` , however I couldn't find any answers that suggests use of `Convert.ToInt32(Enum)`.

Is there any reason for preferring typecast over using Convert.ToInt32 ?

Comment: I think you're talking about this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/909884/2187558

Comment: Readability is better with casting like (int) Enum

Comment: The underlying type is already an int, you don't need to _convert_ it from an other datatype.

Comment: umm, because `enum`'s **are** `int`'s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, enums inherit from `int`, i.e. behind the scenes it is:

```
enum Foo : int
    {
        A,
        B
    }
```

In C#, there is no difference between `Int32` and `int`. So using `Convert.ToInt32(Foo.A)` is a bit redundant, since performing `(int)Foo.A` will suffice. Personally, `(int)Foo.A` also reads much better. Note, you would only really have to watch this in situations where you defined your enum like so:

```
enum Foo : long
    {
       A,
       B
    }
```