# Bind ListBox (or Telerik RadListPicker) to Enum

Tags: telerik, mvvm-light, windows-phone-7

I have an enum:

```cs
public enum UnitOfMeasure
{
    Meters,
    Kilometers,
    Yards,
    Miles,
    Time
}
```

and I want to bind it to a ListBox (actually a Telerik RadListPicker, but it works the same):

```html
<telerikInput:RadListPicker
    Header="Measure work in:"
    ItemsSource="{Binding WorkUnitOfMeasure}"
    HeaderStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}"
    x:Name="workUnitsListPicker"
    Margin="18">
</telerikInput:RadListPicker>
```

My View Model:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// The <see cref="WorkUnitOfMeasure" /> property's name.
/// </summary>
public const string WorkUnitOfMeasurePropertyName = "WorkUnitOfMeasure";

private ObservableCollection<Enum<UnitOfMeasure>> _workUnitOfMeasure;
/// <summary>
/// Gets the WorkUnitOfMeasure property.
/// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
/// This property's value is broadcasted by the Messenger's default instance when it changes.
/// </summary>
public ObservableCollection<Enum<UnitOfMeasure>> WorkUnitOfMeasure
{
    get
    {
        return _workUnitOfMeasure;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_workUnitOfMeasure == value)
        {
            return;
        }
        var oldValue = _workUnitOfMeasure;
        _workUnitOfMeasure = value;
         RaisePropertyChanged(WorkUnitOfMeasurePropertyName);
    }
}
```

And in my constructor I have tried variations of something like this:

```cs
WorkUnitOfMeasure = new ObservableCollection<Enum<UnitOfMeasure>>();
```

I can't seem to get the listbox to bind to Enum.  I know I'm missing something simple, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: The heck is `Enum<UnitOfMeasure>`?  Not sure if WP7 has the ObjectDataSource, but if so this is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145888/how-to-bind-an-enum-to-a-combobox-control-in-wpf

Comment: @JeffCren: Are you binding single enum or list of UnitOfMeasure enums?

Comment: I am trying to bind the list of enums to a dropdown list.

Comment: @Will: WP7 does not have the ObjectDataSource. I saw that question before I posted mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it should be an

```
ObservableCollection<UnitOfMeasure>
```

not

```
ObservableCollection<Enum<UnitOfMeasure>
```

If not what error are you seeing?

Comment: I don't get an error, but the listbox just doesn't bind - it's empty.

Comment: I just noticed that in the viewmodel constructor, when I call WorkUnitOfMeasure = new ObservableCollection<UnitOfMeasure>(); the count on WorkUnitOfMeasure is 0, so it's not getting initialized correctly. It may not be the binding actually, but the initializing.

Comment: @JeffCren: You do know that you have to *add the different values of the enum to the collection*, right?  Its not like the collection fills itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are binding the single enum items to listbox:

Following code may help you:

```
 List<string> newList = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= (int)UnitOfMeasure.Time; i++)
            newList.Add(Enum.GetName(typeof(UnitOfMeasure), i));
        SampleList.ItemsSource = newList;
```