# MarkupExtension with binding parameters

Tags: wpf, binding

I am working on a custom `MarkupExtension` in which I need a non string parameters from XAML to construct the new object. Is it possible to use a non-string parameter binding on a field in `DataContext` scope?

In other words, how can I do something like this?

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={local:MyMarkupExtension {x:Type Button},IncludeMethods={Binding Source=CustomerObject.IsProblematic}}}" />
```

where `IncludeMethods=CustomerObject.IsProblematic` give me this error:

> Binding cannot be set on the 'IncludeMethods' property of type 'TypeDescriptorExtension'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

Can anyone help me?

thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MarkupExtension that uses a DataBinding value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737126/markupextension-that-uses-a-databinding-value)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject - it is true. The problem is that `MarkupExtension` class does not derive from `DependencyObject`, that's why it is not possible to set binding on it's properties.

**[EDIT]**

Workaround is using [ValueConverters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx). Another workaround is to change C# language to allow multiple inheritance. By the way, in Silverlight `MarkupExtension` implements `IMarkupExtension` interface, so I tried to implement it in my custom extension and derive it from `DependecyObject`, added `DependencyProperty` there and set binding to it. It doesn't crash, but the binding is actually set **after** ProvideValue() is called. So even in Silverlight there's no solution (or it is difficult - see link provided in [Klaus78's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10329383/951186)). In WPF MarkupExtension doesn't implement any interface, so you cannot bind to it's properties.

Comment: Changing the C# language to allow multiple inheritance is not exactly what I would call a "workaround" ;)

Comment: Changing the C# language would be the most elegant solutions IMO. You can find the source code of the .Net Framework here: https://github.com/dotnet (there are multiple repositories). I think that you have to edit the CLR which can be found here https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr

Comment: @Snicker Calm, sarcastic and made my day! :D Yay, let's all fork the .NET framework.....

Answer (score 2):

So as other have said, please first consider using a [ValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx).  This is the proper approach for manipulating bindings.

If however, you still want to use a MarkupExtension with bindings to the view-model or data context then you can create the binding manually in the markup extension class.  This is similar to the approach taken by @nicolay.anykienko but we don't need to create an attached property.

As an example, I have created a currency symbol markup extension.  The default behaviour is to use the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` but a few view-models have their own CultureInfo property that are different from the current culture.  So for these view-models the XAML needs to bind to this property.  Note that this could easily be done with a Converter instead, but for the sake of an example here is the markup extension:

```
public class CurrencySymbolExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var targetProvider = (IProvideValueTarget)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget));
        var targetElement = targetProvider.TargetObject as FrameworkElement;
        var targetProperty = targetProvider.TargetProperty as DependencyProperty;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(CultureBindingPath) &&
            targetElement != null &&
            targetProperty != null)
        {
            // make sure that if the binding context changes then the binding gets updated.
            targetElement.DataContextChanged +=
                (sender, args) => ApplyBinding(targetElement, targetProperty, args.NewValue);

            // apply a binding to the target
            var binding = ApplyBinding(targetElement, targetProperty, targetElement.DataContext);

            // return the initial value of the property
            return binding.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
        }
        else
        {
            // if no culture binding is provided then use the current culture
            return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol;
        }
    }

    private Binding ApplyBinding(DependencyObject target, DependencyProperty property, object source)
    {
        BindingOperations.ClearBinding(target, property);

        var binding = new Binding(CultureBindingPath + ".NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol")
        {
            Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
            Source = source,
            FallbackValue = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol,
        };

        BindingOperations.SetBinding(target, property, binding);
        return binding;
    }

    public string CultureBindingPath { get; set; }
}
```

This then gets used as follows:

```
<!-- Standard Usage -->
<TextBlock Text="{local:CurrencySymbol}"/>

<!-- With DataContext Binding -->
<TextBlock Text="{local:CurrencySymbol CultureBindingPath=ViewModelCulture}"/>
```

Where `ViewModelCulture` is the property on the view-model being used as the source of the binding.

Answer (score 0):

This link is informative about

[Custom Markup Extension with bindable properties](https://web.archive.org/web/20180812100041/http://blogs.profitbase.com/tsenn/?p=73)

**EDIT**
Someone made me note that this works only for Silverlight, because in **WPF** `MarkupExtension` doesn't implement `IMarkupExtension` interface. (Thank you EvAlex)

Comment: It works only for Silverlight, because in WPF MarkupExtension doesn't implement IMarkupExtension interface

Comment: Also works in Xamarin Forms. Yay, finally found a feature where Xamarin Forms is ahead of WPF  :P

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this problem.
The main idea is to define attached property for each parameter that requires binding.

```
public class MarkupExtensionWithBindableParam : MarkupExtension
{
    public BindingBase Param1 { get; set; } // its necessary to set parameter type as BindingBase to avoid exception that binding can't be used with non DependencyProperty

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        IProvideValueTarget target = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget)) as IProvideValueTarget;
        DependencyObject targetObject;
        DependencyProperty targetProperty;
        
        if (target != null && target.TargetObject is DependencyObject && target.TargetProperty is DependencyProperty)
        {
            targetObject = (DependencyObject)target.TargetObject;
            targetProperty = (DependencyProperty)target.TargetProperty;
        }
        else
        {
            return this; // magic
        }

        // Bind the Param1 to attached property Param1BindingSinkProperty 
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(targetObject, MarkupExtensionWithBindableParam.Param1BindingSinkProperty, Param1);

        // Now you can use Param1
        
        // Param1 direct access example:
        object param1Value = targetObject.GetValue(Param1BindingSinkProperty);
        
        // Param1 use in binding example:
        var param1InnerBinding = new Binding() { Source = targetObject, Path = new PropertyPath("(0).SomeInnerProperty", Param1BindingSinkProperty) }); // binding to Param1.SomeInnerProperty
        return param1InnerBinding.ProvideValue(serviceProvider); // return binding to Param1.SomeInnerProperty
    }

    private static DependencyProperty Param1BindingSinkProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Param1BindingSink", typeof(object)// set the desired type of Param1 for at least runtime type safety check
                       , typeof(MarkupExtensionWithBindableParam ), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));
}
```

Usage is straightforward:

```
<TextBlock Text="{local:MarkupExtensionWithBindableParam Param1={Binding Path='SomePathToParam1'}}"/>
```

Comment: There is a problem with the *Usage* example. Doesn't the markup have to be in quotes?

Comment: @nicolay.anykienko I didn't test the solution but please check if my edit works for you, xaml syntax

Comment: It needs something extra for it to work in (data)templates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44106154/bindingexpressionbase-is-null-in-custom-markupextension

In code, this means adding this at the start of the ProvideValue method: 

if(serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget)) is IProvideValueTarget targetProvider &&
                targetProvider.TargetObject != null && !(targetProvider.TargetObject is DependencyObject)) return this;

Comment: This code doesn't seem to be a working solution. I'm not sure how to modify it to be one. RegisterAttached fails with "Unexpected record in Baml stream.  Trying to add to MarkupExtensionWithBindableParam which is not a collection or has a TypeConverter." My advice is to look somewhere else if you were looking for an answer.