# How to use a converter on a hard-coded value in xaml

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a Windows Phone app which I want to be localized. Because I download the translation from a server on runtime, I can't use AppResources for this. What I would want to do is create a converter which changes the key to the string in the translated value. 
Something like :

```
    Text="{"STRING_OK", Converter={StaticResource TranslationConverter}}"
```

Of course, this code doesn't compile, but is there a workaround for this? How could I use the converter for hard-coded values?

Comment: technically a Converter is used in Binding context only. No binding, no converter. I think your issue can be solved with a workaround by using some custom MarkupExtension which accepts an input string, it then will convert the string to some another value depending on the target culture.

Comment: As @KingKing said it has to be done using MarkupExtension. Go through these links- 

 1. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14839496/442444
 2. http://wpftutorial.net/LocalizeMarkupExtension.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another possible workaround which simpler than creating `MarkupExtension` is to set the hard-coded value as converter parameter. Anyway, as @KingKing already pointed, binding is still required for us to be able to use `Converter`. We can just make the converter ignore value passed via binding and only consider `ConverterParameter` in the conversion logic  :

```
Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TranslationConverter}, 
               ConverterParameter=STRING_OK}"
```

Comment: That's strange, worked fine for me without having to create a dummy string. Could you share the binding statement you tried?

Comment: You are right, I wasn't using the ConvertParameter correctly (I was passing the parameter as a string). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you could not create a fixed number of AppResources for various languages since your case is a dynamic translation process, but still you can create a single Appresource file for your hardcoded string values and then you can use a converter of our own.

Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.TextLabelLocale, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings},Converter={StaticResource TranslationConverter}}"

public class LocalizedStrings
    {
        public LocalizedStrings()
        {
        }

```
    private static sdkGlobalizationCS.AppResources localizedResources = new sdkGlobalizationCS.AppResources();

    public sdkGlobalizationCS.AppResources LocalizedResources { get { return localizedResources; } }
}
```