# Apply ValueConverter in style when source comes from x:Static resx file

Tags: wpf, xaml, ivalueconverter, wpf-style

After quite some search and reading other questions & posts, I was not able to find how to solve this. Note: I'm relatively new to WPF (not to binding in general).

Here's what I'm after:

1. I'd like to have all TextBlock controls in a window to be styled in some way.
2. The style should also apply a ValueConverter to make text all uppercase.
3. Finally, each TextBlock Text could come either from binding to a view-model property, or from binding to a resource string from a .resx file

Here's an excerpt of what I'm playing with:

```xml
<!-- in Window resources -->
<help:AllCapsStringConverter x:Key="AllCaps"/>

<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Brown" />
    <Setter Property="Text">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Binding>
                <Binding.Converter>
                    <help:AllCapsStringConverter />
                </Binding.Converter>
                <!-- also tried adding:
                <Binding.RelativeSource>
                    <RelativeSource Mode="Self" />
                </Binding.RelativeSource>
                -->
            </Binding>

            <!-- also tried with: 
            <Binding Converter="{StaticResource AllCaps}"/>

            <Binding Path="Text" Converter="{StaticResource AllCaps}"/>
            -->
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!-- in Window content -->
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static resx:MyResources.MyTitle}" />
```

Here's the value converter, which on its own has proved to be working:

```cs
class AllCapsStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && value is string)
        {
            return ((string)value).ToUpper();
        }
        else
        {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

TextBlocks get the foreground color, but no conversion kicks in.

I was able to apply the converter locally to the single TextBlock, but I don't want to apply that to all TextBlocks around the window:

```xml
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <Binding Source="{x:Static resx:MyResources.MyTitle}"
                 Converter="{StaticResource AllCaps}"/>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
<!-- which is the same as -->
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource CustomerInfoTitleStyle}" 
           Text="{Binding Source={x:Static resx:MyResources.MyTitle}, Converter={StaticResource AllCaps}}" />
```

Comment: Have you tried `<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"`? And in your Binding: `<Binding Converter="AllCaps">`. HTH

Comment: For `TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"`: I already know that style is applied correctly, because other Setters works (e.g. foreground color, font size, etc.).

Comment: For `<Binding Converter="AllCaps">`, sorry I did not get where should I try that.

Comment: ok and have you tried the Binding?

Comment: `<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Brown" />
    <Setter Property="Text">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Binding Converter="AllCaps">`

Comment: I just tried that know, in the meantime, and that does not even compile. Which makes sense, as I don't think you can refer to the converter by its Key without *binding* that to its static resource.
Anyway I tried with `<Binding Converter="{StaticResource AllCaps}" />` and it compiles but doesn't work.

Comment: have a go at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737126/markupextension-that-uses-a-databinding-value) then. This would be perfect for you to determine custom conditions for your binding. This link is just an example of the custom binding. HTH

Comment: thanks for suggestion. At the moment I'm settling with the ControlTemplate solution provided by answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a 'Label' and build a template, because a ['TextBlock' is not a control](https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/07/04/differences-between-label-and-textblock/).

```
<Style x:Key="AllCapsLabel" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Label">
                <TextBlock Foreground="Brown" Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource AllCaps}}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And use it this way:

```
<Label Style="{StaticResource AllCapsLabel}" Content="whatever you want" />
```

If the content is plain text (aka a 'String'), the text should always be uppercase.

Answer (score 2):

Your converter is not working because your `TextBlock` is overriding the `Text` property of the `Style`, which includes the converter you have added to the binding.

For example:

```
<Grid.Resources>

    <Style x:Key="MyTextBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="You won't see this."></Setter>
    </Style>

</Grid.Resources>

<TextBlock Text="You will see this." Style="{StaticResource MyTextBlockStyle}"/>
```

Hopefully from the above you can see why your approach is not working.

A better solution would just be to set the value of `Text` with the value converter on the `TextBlock`, rather than in the `Style`.

If you don't want to do that, one common cheat you could use to get around this could be to bind the TextBlock's Text property to the Tag property, like so:

```
<Grid.Resources>

    <local:AllCapsConverter x:Key="AllCaps"/>

    <Style x:Key="MyTextBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource AllCaps}}"/>
    </Style>

</Grid.Resources>

<TextBlock Tag="You will see this." Style="{StaticResource MyTextBlockStyle}"/>
```

I have a strong dislike of this approach, but it does get you what you want. I would prefer you just use the converter when you set the binding on the `TextBlock`.

lukegv's approach is another alternative. However, there is no need to use a `Label`, as you are overriding the template and (similar to my example above) you are just binding to the `Content` property of the `Label`. You could just as easily get what you need from a `ContentControl`.

```
<Grid.Resources>

    <local:AllCapsConverter x:Key="AllCaps"/>

    <Style x:Key="MyContentControl" TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource AllCaps}}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</Grid.Resources>

<ContentControl Style="{StaticResource MyContentControl}" Content="You will see this too!"/>
```

I'm not a particularly huge fan of this idea either though, as you lose access to all the other `TextBlock` properties. For example, if I wanted to set the `FontWeight` property of my `TextBlock` then I would be stuffed.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I too dislike that *diverting* of properties to represent some other meaning, different than what was intended originally. I understand that at this point a ContentControl might be equivalent, as we are completely replacing Label template and binding to content. Although I can say that leaving Label instead of ContentControl reminds somehow better of what that control is supposed to be (a text label)