# ObjectDataProvider as source for a ComboBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, f#

I have defined on my ViewModel class a static property named

```ml
static member GetColumnTypes = FSharpType.GetUnionCases typeof<ColumnType>
```

where ColumnType is a normal union type

```ml
type ColumnType   = T_Link of TableName | T_Real | T_Bool | T_Int | T_String
```

---

I don't understand the logic at play in XAML to bind to such a collection in the following scenarios :

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="typelist" MethodName="GetColumnTypes" ObjectType="{x:Type local:MarkupViewModel}"/>
  <local:MarkupViewModel x:Key="defaultVM" d:IsDataSource="True"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

  //1-WORKS
  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource defaultVM}, Path=GetColumnTypes}"></ComboBox> 

  //2-DOES NOT WORK
  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource typelist}}"></ComboBox>

  //3-DOES NOT WORK
  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Type local:MarkupViewModel}, Path=GetColumnTypes}"></ComboBox>

  //4-WORKS
  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding  Path=GetColumnTypes}" />
```

1. Why does this work ? I though the static ressource named `defaultVM` was creating an object using the parameterless constructor. On this object, there is no method GetColumnTypes !
2. Why does it not work ? I thought I was calling `GetColumnTypes` on the type specified. and if I look at [example getting Enum values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145888/how-to-bind-an-enum-to-a-combobox-control-in-wpf), it seems to be what is happening. my case is jsut simpler as it has no parameters
3. Again, does this not call he method on the mentionned type ?
4. Here I set the datacontext to an instance of my Viremodel, and it 'magically' knows hos to go from the instance to a static method.

Beside those questions, I feel like it is very much black box magic, and I see very little information about the binding process.

What is the best approach to make it clear ?
Are there may be some debugging tool available for the Binding process ?

Answer (score 3):

There are two things to know that should clear things up:

First, in XAML, you can access static members through an instance of the type.
You can also do this in VB.NET, for instance with this code:

```
Dim x = New MarkupViewModel()
x.GetColumnTypes
MarkupViewModel.GetColumnTypes
```

The last two lines are equivalent. In fact, the compiler rewrites the first line as the second. XAML is the same way. If you have an instance, you can access a static member through the same syntax as an instance member. (Other languages, like C# and F#, don't allow this syntax).

Second, `ObjectDataProvider` calls a *method*, but `GetColumnTypes` is a *property*. If you had defined it as `static member GetColumnTypes() = ...` I would expect it to work.

However, none of these approaches are really ideal. What you want to do is use the [x:Static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx) markup extension. This is what it was designed for.

In your namespace definitions (in the topmost tag of the XAML file), write something like this:

```
<UserControl [...] xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Your.Namespace">
```

And then have the combo box declare its items like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Static local:MarkupViewModel.GetColumnTypes}">
```

(although if you're keeping it as a property and not a function you should of course rename it as `ColumnTypes` not `GetColumnTypes`)

Oh, and as for diagnosing binding errors, quite a lot of debugging information is available through `Visual Studio Options > Debugging > Output Window > WPF Trace Settings`, which can dump a lot of information to the output window. However they can be somewhat difficult to interpret if you don't know WPF very well. An excellent general-purpose WPF utility is [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/), which is good for many other reasons, but it can also display binding error information.

Comment: I realized a few things when going away from the problem a bit, like the static thing. I already use snoop but did not realize it could show bindings traces. This is all very helpful, thank you.

Comment: The C# static rewriting seems wrong though. for instance : var a = (new DateTime()).Now; => Error 2 Member 'System.DateTime.Now.get' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Comment: Oops, you are right. I was tired and mixed up which language supports that syntax (it's a 'feature' that leads to programming errors so I don't really think about it that often). It's VB.NET where those lines are equivalent (also Java and probably a few others). I'll fix my answer.