# Get error message when appear

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a textbox and is bound to a property.

```
public SapLanguage Language
{
    get { return _language; }
    set
    {
        _language = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

The SapLanguage is type enum:

```
public enum SapLanguage
{
    DE,
    EN,
    FR,
    IT
}
```

The WPF looks like as follow:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,10,10,10" FontSize="26" FontWeight="Bold"
                     CharacterCasing="Upper"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" MaxLength="2" Width="60"
                     HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Language, StringFormat={} }">
</TextBox>
```

When I type a value in the textbox, that does not exist. It shows me an error:

[image]

How can I store the error message into a variable?

Comment: Check its Validation property, HasError property and Errors collection. There is also an Error event you can attach a trigger to.

Comment: How can I implement Validation property?

Comment: Starting pont: https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.controls.validation(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Why `TextBox`? See @FranzWimmer answer, `ComboBox` is preferable, then you don't need validation at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For binding an *enum* to a `TextBox` you would need a converter class that implements the `IValueConverter` interface.

For displaying an enum, i wold prefer using a `ComboBox` instead, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6145957/5764665