# Adding value to array within xaml using x:Static

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, contentproperty

For example, I have to use array of string inside my `xaml`

```
<x:Array Type="sys:String" x:Key="Statuses">
    <sys:String>Ok</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Warning</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Error</sys:String>
</x:Array>
```

But what if I have to assing items via `x:Static`. Is it possible ? Following code doesn't work.

```
<x:Array Type="system:String" x:Key="Statuses">
    <sys:String>
        <Binding="{x:Static model:Status.Ok}" />
    </sys:String>
    <sys:String>
        <Binding="{x:Static model:Status.Warning}" />
    </sys:String>
</x:Array>

public enum Status
{
    Ok,
    Warning,
    Error
}
```

So my question is how to initialize array within `xaml` using `x:Static`

I know this approach

```
[ContentProperty("Values")]
[ContentWrapper(typeof(Collection<State>))]
public class StateCollection
{
    private const string DefaultKeySeparator = ",";
    private string _keySeparator;
    public string KeySeparator
    {
        get { return _keySeparator ?? DefaultKeySeparator; }
        set { _keySeparator = value; }
    }
    private Collection<State> _values = new Collection<AlternationConverterItem>();
    public Collection<State> Values
    {
        get { return _values; }
        set { _values = value; }
    }
}

public sealed class State
{
    public Status Status { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
}

<myNamespace:StateCollection x:Key="MyCollection" KeySeparator="-">
    <myNamespace:State Status="{x:Static model:RestoreObjectStatus.Ok}" Description="{StaticResource Description1}" />
    <myNamespace:State Status="{x:Static model:RestoreObjectStatus.Warning}" Description="{StaticResource Description2}" />
    <myNamespace:State Status="{x:Static model:RestoreObjectStatus.Error}" Description="{StaticResource Description3}" />
</myNamespace:AlternationConverter2>
```

But I don't kwni hot to apply the same way for array of string I've writen above.

Comment: it seems `Items` property does not have accessible setter so unfortunately you cant use object data provider like used in this way... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145888/how-to-bind-an-enum-to-a-combobox-control-in-wpf

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary And ContentProperty and ContentWrapper couldn't help with this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've successefully used `x:Static Member=`:

```
<x:Array x:Key="SiteOkKey" Type="system:Object">
    <x:Static Member="model:RestoreObjectStatus.Ok" />
    <x:Static Member="core:RestoreObjectTypes.Site" />
</x:Array>
```