# Combox not updating with binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Everytime i change my selected item inside my UI it's not updating my combobox.

**XAML**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="CompanyComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" 
    Margin="100,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="144" 
    SelectionChanged="CompanyComboBox_SelectionChanged" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCompany, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPresenter 
                Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource DescriptionConverter}}">
            </ContentPresenter>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>    
</ComboBox>
```

**C#**

```
private Company _selectedCompany;

public Company SelectedCompany
{
    get { return _selectedCompany; }
    set
    {
        if (value == _selectedCompany)
            return;
        _selectedCompany = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedCompany));
    }
}
```

Just to clarify the Company class is actually an ENUM

DescriptionConverter:

```
public class CompanyDescriptionConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var type = typeof(Company);
        var name = Enum.GetName(type, value);
        FieldInfo fi = type.GetField(name);
        var descriptionAttrib = (DescriptionAttribute)
            Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(fi, typeof(DescriptionAttribute));

        return descriptionAttrib.Description;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

what i mean by inside my UI, is i have a list of companies set to a combobox item source, and when i change the combobox value to another company, it doesn't update in my source, it stay's as default.

My Enum might clarify the problem for someone:

```
 [Description("Netpoint Solutions")]
    Company1 = 0,

    [Description("Blackhall Engineering")]
    Company2 = 180,
```

Comment: What does your DescriptionConverter look like? Is it ever invoked? And what exactly do you mean by "change my selected item inside my UI" -- does that mean you select something in this particular combobox? Seeing more of your code would be helpful.

Comment: @PetterHesselberg updated thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove `Mode=OneWayToSource` and your event handler:

```
SelectionChanged="CompanyComboBox_SelectionChanged"
```

You don't need to handle the `SelectionChanged` event when you bind the `SelectedItem` property.

Also make sure that you set the `DataContext` to an instance of your class where the `SelectedCompany` property is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Your Binding is defined as OneWayToSource. When you want it to be updated from the viewModel, you should set it to TwoWay.

See the documentation of Bindings for more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx

EDIT:

I skipped the part where you have an `Enum` as the source. I do not see, that you define the `ItemsSource` for the `Combobox`, where is this done? The value passed to the `setter` of `SelectedCompany` has to be in the Collection defined as `ItemsSource`.

For Enums, you can refer to this thread: [How to bind an enum to a combobox control in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145888/how-to-bind-an-enum-to-a-combobox-control-in-wpf)

Comment: i had it set to TwoWay aswell, still nothing happens when i change my selected item.

Comment: i define the itemsource like this             CompanyComboBox.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Company)).Cast<Company>();

Comment: What exactly do you expect to happen?

Comment: i expect it to be bound? so when i change my selected item from company1 to company 2, the SelectedCompany field should update to Company2 then i can use that throughout the clas.

Comment: Should work if the types match and you remove " Mode=OneWayToSource". Did you put a breakpoint in the setter of SelectedCompany? And what are you doing in CompanyComboBox_SelectionChanged?

Comment: i have added a breakpoint inside the SelecCompanySetter, it doesn't get hit when my property changes.

Comment: What about your event handler? Try to remove it. And how do you set the DataContext?