# WPF combobox is empty when binding enum

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I am trying to bind values of an enum to a combo box but the combo box remain empty with no options to choose.

This is the combo box xaml defintion:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SkillItemSource}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=neededSkill, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedIndex="0" Margin="5" MinWidth="100"></ComboBox>
```

And this is the items source and selected item which are defined in the window's cs:

```
public Skill neededSkill = Skill.FirstSkill;

public string[] SkillItemSource
    {
        get
        {
            return Enum.GetNames(typeof(Skill));
        }
    }
```

What is missing for the values to appear in the combobox?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145888/how-to-bind-an-enum-to-a-combobox-control-in-wpf) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: You cannot set SelectedItem to type Skill while the ItemsSource of Combobox is type string[].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is missing for the values to appear in the combobox?

You need to set the `DataContext` of the `ComboBox`, or a parent element, to an instance of the class where the `SkillItemSource` property is defined. If the property is defined in the code-behind, you could just set the DataContext to the view itself: `this.DataContext = this;`

Also, you can't mix types. If the `ItemsSource` is bound to an `IEnumerable<string>`, the `SelectedItem` property should be bound to a `string` property.

Also note that `neededSkill` must be defined as a public *property* for you to be able to bind to it.

Try this:

```
public Skill neededSkill { get; set; } = Skill.FirstSkill;

public IEnumerable<Skill> SkillItemSource { get; } = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Skill)).Cast<Skill>();
```

Comment: Do I need to set the DataContext even if it's defined in the xaml.cs of that same window?

Comment: Yes. If the property is defined in the code-behind, you could just set the DataContext to the view itself: `this.DataContext = this;`