# WPF Binding Enum on a ComboBox MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, enums, combobox

In my project I need to bing the following enum

```
public enum eFlex_IO_COMP_CM
{
    ePan = 0,
    eComp = 1,
}
```

into a combobox. I've a public list, valorized as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<eFlex_IO_COMP_CM> EnumFlexIoCompCm { get; set; }

EnumFlexIoCompCm = Enum.GetValues(typeof(eFlex_IO_COMP_CM)).Cast<eFlex_IO_COMP_CM>();
```

This is the XAML code:

```
<ComboBox 
    Grid.Column="20" 
    Width="50" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=EnumFlexIoCompCm, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:ViewerFlexConfig}}" 
    SelectionChanged="Combo_SelectionChanged" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Value" 
    SelectedValuePath="Key" 
    SelectedValue="{Binding ConfigObject.COMP_CounterMode, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    />
```

Basically I want to display the name of enum's item and set the key as value because I need to store in the database the int and not the description.
The problem is that I cannot even display the name of enum's item and set correctly the value, as If I try to save, the value from that combobox is name. Any helps?

Comment: this helped me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145888/how-to-bind-an-enum-to-a-combobox-control-in-wpf

Comment: Note that `IEnumerable<eFlex_IO_COMP_CM>` is not a Dictionary. The elements do not have a `Key` and a `Value` property. Consider changing the type of the EnumFlexIoCompCm to `Dictionary<int, string>`.

Comment: And of course if the integer values are consecutive, starting at 0, you may simply bind the ItemsSource to a collection of strings or enum values, and then bind the SelectedIndex property.

Comment: Remove `DisplayMemberPath="Value" and SelectedValuePath="Key"`. Then you should see the "name" of the enumeration values in the `ComboBox`. `ConfigObject.COMP_CounterMode` should be an `eFlex_IO_COMP_CM` property that you can simply cast to an `int` whenever you need: `int val = (int)eFlex_IO_COMP_CM;`

Comment: Perfect @Clemens, I converted my IEnumerable into Dictionary and all works fine, thanks!