# How to bind a wpf Combobox to an Enum type and display it in the Combobox as a Description where the Enum is defined?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, enums, combobox

```cs
public enum IVAC_VT_SHIFT_SPD
{
    [Description("16.1299991607666")]
    DATA16,
    [Description("32.130001068115234")]
    DATA32,
}
```

```xml
<ComboBox Grid.Row="8"
          Grid.Column="2"
          Width="194"
          Height="40"
          Margin="0,0,3,0"
          HorizontalAlignment="Right"
          VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource IVAC_VT_SHIFT_SPD}}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding VTShiftSPD}" />

<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="IVAC_VT_SHIFT_SPD"
                    MethodName="GetValues"
                    ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <x:Type TypeName="enm:IVAC_VT_SHIFT_SPD" />
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

```cs
private IVAC_VT_SHIFT_SPD _VTShiftSPD = IVAC_VT_SHIFT_SPD.DATA16;
public IVAC_VT_SHIFT_SPD VTShiftSPD
{
    get => _VTShiftSPD;
    set
    {
        _VTShiftSPD = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(VTShiftSPD));
    }
}
```

What I want is to bind the enum type value to the Combobox. However, I want the contents of the Combobox to be displayed as the contents of the Description. The selection must be selected as an enum.

1. Is there a way to do it without using a converter?
2. Is there a way to get it done only in Xaml?
3. I want a simple method.

Comment: Have a look at [Brian Lagunas: A Better Way to Data Bind Enums in WPF](https://brianlagunas.com/a-better-way-to-data-bind-enums-in-wpf/) - but it is not everything done in XAML. You still need some code for declaring the enum, the property in the ViewModel and the helper classes. And it is more than a method

Comment: <ComboBox Grid.Row="8"
          Grid.Column="2"
          Width="194"
          Height="40"
          Margin="0,0,3,0"
          HorizontalAlignment="Right"
          VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Type enm:IVAC_VT_SHIFT_SPD}}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding VTShiftSPD}">

    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource EnumToDescriptionConverter}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>

Comment: I did this in Converter: GetDescription((Enum)value); An InvalidException is thrown when called.

Comment: If you want to add more details to the question then **edit** the question by clicking on the Edit link (at the bottom of the question and above the comment section). Posting Code in the comments is a very bad idea (if you look at it)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bind an enum to a combobox control in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145888/how-to-bind-an-enum-to-a-combobox-control-in-wpf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enums are not meant to be displayed in the UI. Enums are a simple enumeration of integral numbers where each value has an associated name.
Your scenario is simply beyond the intent of the `enum` type.

If you want to define a set of constants where each constant carries along data then you should define a type (`class` or `struct`). This will also give you more flexibility in terms of presenting the data in view - without the additional overhead of converters and reflection. You will end up with much cleaner and natural/intuitive code. Using `enum` in your scenario is just not graceful and adds no benefit. An `enum` must be representative without any metadata stored in attributes or tables.

You can even consider to make this custom type to define a property of that `enum` if the `enum` itself does make sense - which is only the case if the type is not an extension of the `enum` (to carry meta data), because the `enum` values must be able to stand alone i.e. consumed without the metadata.

For example, if you create an enum `Color` which has values like `Color.Red` and those values can't be consumed without the actual red color value then `Color.Red` should not be an enum but a `class` or a `struct` that is able to define that metadata.

A suggested solution could look as follows:

**VTShiftSPD.cs**

```cs
// TODO::Implement IEquatable<VTShiftSPD> (don't forget to override GetHashCode)
public readonly struct VTShiftSPD : IEquatable<VTShiftSPD>
{
  public const string Data16 = "DATA16";
  public const string Data32 = "DATA32";

  public VTShiftSPD(string id, double value)
  {
    this.Id = id;
    this.Value = value;
  }

  public string Id { get; }
  public double Value { get; }
}
```

You can use and compare it e.g. as follows (without any reflection!):

```cs
static Main()
{
  var vTShiftSPD = new VTShiftSPD(VTShiftSPD.Data16, 16.1299991607666);
  Evaluate(vTShiftSPD);
}

private static void Evaluate(VTShiftSPD vTShiftSPD)
{
  switch (vTShiftSPD.Id)
  {
    case VTShiftSPD.Data16: break;
    case VTShiftSPD.Data32: break;
    default: break;
  }
}
```

And if the set of instances created from `VTShiftSPD` are not an open set you can even define them as constants themselves:

**VTShiftSPDs.cs**

```cs
static class VTShiftSPDs
{
  public static readonly VTShiftSPD Spd16 = new VTShiftSPD(VTShiftSPD.Data16, 16.1299991607666);
  public static readonly VTShiftSPD Spd32 = new VTShiftSPD(VTShiftSPD.Data32, 32.130001068115234);
}
```

And use it as follows:

```cs
static Main()
{
  Evaluate(VTShiftSPDs.Spd16);
}

private static void Evaluate(VTShiftSPD vTShiftSPD)
{
  switch (vTShiftSPD.Id)
  {
    case VTShiftSPD.Data16: break;
    case VTShiftSPD.Data32: break;
    default: break;
  }
}
```

And gracefully (and efficiently) use it to populate the data view:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
// The data source for the ComboBox.ItemsSource
public ObservableCollection<VTShiftSPD> VTShiftSPDs { get; } 
  = new ObservableCollection<VTShiftSPD> 
  { 
    VTShiftSPDs.Spd16,
    VTShiftSPDs.Spd32,
  };
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <StackPanel>
    <ComboBox x:Name="VTShiftSPDSelector"
              ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType Window}, Path=VTShiftSPDs}"
              DisplayMemberPath="Value" />

    <Stackpanel DataContext="{Binding Elementname=VTShiftSPDSelector, Path=SelectedItem}>
      <TextBlock x:Name="Id"
                 Text{Binding Id}" /> <!-- Displays e.g. DATA16 -->
      <TextBlock x:Name="Value"
                 Text{Binding Value}" /> <!-- Displays e.g. 16.1299991607666 -->
    </StackPanel>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can get pretty close accomplishing what you are looking for. I did use a couple C# classes to accomplish it, but those will work for any future enums without you needing to constantly create additional classes or code behind to facilitate getting the descriptions in the dropdown.

In my sample, I am able to produce the following result

```cs
namespace Enums
{
   public enum IVAC_VT_SHIFT_SPD
   {
      [Description("16.1299991607666")]
      DATA16,
      [Description("32.130001068115234")]
      DATA32,
   }
}
```

```xml
<Window ...
   xmlns:enums="clr-namespace:StackOverflowAnswers.Wpf.Enums"
   ...>

<ComboBox x:Name="Combo"
   ItemsSource="{Binding Source={enums:EnumBindingSource {x:Type enums:IVAC_VT_SHIFT_SPD}}}"
   DisplayMemberPath="Description"
   SelectedValuePath="Value" />
```

[image]

To facilitate this, I used an adaptation of the approach outlined in this link: https://brianlagunas.com/a-better-way-to-data-bind-enums-in-wpf/. If you follow that directly, you can achieve pretty similar results without a ViewModel for the enum. However, I like using the ViewModel, since it will allow me to potentially tweak things as needed, like maybe add support for a icon attribute.

In my example, I created an `EnumViewModel` class to house what will be displayed in the combobox:

```cs
namespace Enums
{
    public class EnumViewModel
    {
        public EnumViewModel(Enum value)
        {
            Value = value;
            Description = getDescription(value);
        }

        public Enum Value { get; }
        public string Description { get; }

        private string getDescription(Enum value)
        {
            if (!(value?.GetType().GetField(value?.ToString()) is FieldInfo enumField))
                // value is null...
                return string.Empty;

            var descriptionAttribute = enumField.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)
                .OfType<DescriptionAttribute>()
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if (descriptionAttribute is null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(descriptionAttribute.Description))
                // description attribute is missing or blank...
                return value.ToString();

            return descriptionAttribute.Description;
        }
    }
}
```

And a `MarkupExtension` to allow me to bind to that directly without having to include it in a view model or code behind. This sets up the ability to use `Source={enums:EnumBindingSource ...}`.

```cs
namespace Enums
{
    public class EnumBindingSourceExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        private Type _enumType;
        public Type EnumType
        {
            get => this._enumType;
            set
            {
                if (value == this._enumType) return;

                if (!isEnumType(value)) throw new ArgumentException("Type must be for an Enum.");

                this._enumType = value;
            }
        }

        private bool isEnumType(Type type)
        {
            if (type is null) return false;
            var enumType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) ?? type;
            return enumType.IsEnum;
        }

        public EnumBindingSourceExtension() { }

        public EnumBindingSourceExtension(Type enumType)
        {
            this.EnumType = enumType;
        }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (this._enumType is null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The EnumType must be specified.");

            var actualEnumType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(this._enumType) ?? this._enumType;
            var enumValues = Enum.GetValues(actualEnumType)
                .OfType<Enum>()
                .Select(x => new EnumViewModel(x))
                .ToList();

            return enumValues;
        }
    }
}
```

Now that these are in place, any future Enums can be bound to ComboBoxes as easily as shown at the start.