# Trying to use [Description] data annotation attribute with existing code

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

**SLIGHT UPDATE BELOW**

I am trying to use the `[Description]` data annotation attribute with `enums` in order to display a friendly name. I've searched around a lot and cannot get anything implemented.  Right now I have code that will display an `enum` as a string (using an extension), but I am not liking `ThisIsAnEnum` as an `enum` name (which is spaced out by the string extension) and it prohibits me from having longer names (which I need to maintain) such as for a radio button item. My goal is to have longer descriptions for radio button items without having to write really long enums. An extension/helper will probably be the right way to go, but I need to "fit" it into the code I am using, which is where I failed using the many examples out there.

The code I am using is generic, in that depending upon some logic either a radio button list, check box list, drop down list, select list or regular text boxes are displayed.  For multi-item lists `enum`'s are used, and the `enum` name is what is displayed (after using the string extension).

Here is the particular code that displays the enum:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetItemsFromEnum<T>
    (T selectedValue = default(T)) where T : struct
    {
        return from name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(T))
               let enumValue = Convert.ToString((T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), name, true))

               select new SelectListItem
               {
                   Text = name.ProperCase(),
                   Value = enumValue,
                   Selected = enumValue.Equals(selectedValue)
               };
    }
```

`ProperCase` is the class that changes the `enum` to something readable.

I found something that almost worked:

```
public static string GetEnumDescription<TEnum>(TEnum value)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

        DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = 
            (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

        if ((attributes != null) && (attributes.Length > 0))
            return attributes[0].Description;
        else
            return value.ToString();
    }
```

in which case I changed code from `Text = name.ProperCase(),` to `Text = name.GetEnumDescription(...)` but if I put `value` in the parenthesis I get a "does not exist in the current context" message (which I tried fixing but just made the problem worse). If I leave it blank I get the "No overload for ... takes 0 arguments" (again, understandable - but I don't know how to fix). And if I put `name` in the parenthesis the code compiles but upon viewing the page I get the "Object reference not set..." error on this line:

```
DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes
    (typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
```

I've spent a lot of time on this and know that my stumbling block is the

```
Text = name.ProperCase(),
```

code. Any ideas/help? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

If I do:

```
Text = GetEnumDescription(selectedValue),
```

I actually DO get the `[Description]` text, however, it just displays for the first enum. So, if I have 5 enums all with different `[Description]`'s the code just repeats the `[Description]` for the first enum 5 times instead of displaying differently for each. I hope that makes sense and gets to narrow down the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the Enum<T> value Description](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297299/get-the-enumt-value-description)

Comment: Not seeing how it's a possible duplicate question. I believe that answers a different problem (or at least I can't get any solution there to work for me), but I defer to your expertise.

Comment: The linked question has the `GetEnumDescription()` part. I didn't see the DropDownList part before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend you the `Display` attribute:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetItemsFromEnum<T>(T selectedValue = default(T)) where T : struct
{
    return 
        from name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(T))
        let enumValue = Convert.ToString((T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), name, true))
        select new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = GetEnumDescription(name, typeof(T)),
            Value = enumValue,
            Selected = name == selectedValue.ToString()
        };
}

public static string GetEnumDescription(string value, Type enumType)
{
    var fi = enumType.GetField(value.ToString());
    var display = fi
        .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false)
        .OfType<DisplayAttribute>()
        .FirstOrDefault();
    if (display != null)
    {
        return display.Name;
    }
    return value;
}
```

and then you could have:

```
public enum Foo
{
    [Display(Name = "value 1")]
    Value1,

    Value2,

    [Display(Name = "value 3")]
    Value3
}
```

And now you could have:

```
var foo = Foo.Value2;
var values = GetItemsFromEnum(foo);
```

Also notice that I have modified the `Selected` clause in the LINQ expression as yours is not correct.

This being said, personally I would recommend you staying away from enums on your view models as they don't play nicely with what's built-in ASP.NET MVC and you will have to reinvent most of the things.

Comment: Thanks for this Darin. It's working to display the attribute for each item, however the `.FirstOrDefault()` line is causing a drop down to bypass the "Select One" text, and in the case of check boxes it's automatically checking the first item (which in my scenario is not preferred). Is there a way around that?  Thanks.

Comment: @REMESQ, try a nullable enum if you want a default value for a select box.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance: I am already doing, for example `public Foo? FooDropDown { get; set; }` and the only way I know how to null an enum is to do `public Foo? FooDropDown = null;` which obviously won't work together. Might I trouble you for an example with the code you posted? Thanks.

Comment: Resolved: I kept the original `Selected` and your solution worked and the check boxes are unchecked and the drop down has the default value of "Select One". Thanks!